# How to chain ssh and stay in prompt

Tags: ssh, linux-mint

I want to create a script that when I double click runs:

1. 'ssh -Y server1'
2. WITHIN server1 run 'ssh -Y server2' (server2 not accessible outside)
3. I now have the terminal prompt connected to server2 waiting to run commands

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What happens, what error messages (if any)?

Comment: It seemed to be stuck in limbo essentially, so no stdin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SSH's `-W` option to achieve this. From the manual:

> **-W host :port**
> Requests  that  standard input and output on the client be forwarded to host on port over the secure channel.  Implies -N, -T, ExitOnForward-Failure and ClearAllForwardings.  Works with Protocol version 2 only.

You can set this up in your `~/.ssh/config` to simplify the process, like so:

```
Host Server1
  Hostname 200.200.200.1
  Port 2222
  User you
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host Server2
  Hostname 192.168.1.2
  Port 3333
  User you
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa

# Hop to 2
Host Server2
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p Server1
```

You then simply `ssh Server2` and—*provided you have set up your authentication correctly*—you will be logged in to Server2.

Comment: Not only does this work, but is a really elegant way to do this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore to what Jason said, another less elegant solution where you don't need to change the config and can enter other ssh parameters like -t and -Y:

```
ssh -tY user@server1 "ssh -tY user@server2; bash -s"
```